# StackOverflow Exception in TypeDescriptor.GetConverter

Tags: c#, .net, ranorex, typedescriptor, icustomtypedescriptor

In two of our automated UI testing machines (Win7 and Win10) running Ranorex, I do get StackOverflow Exceptions from time to time. The stackoverflow occurs within the `TypeDescriptor.GetConverter`. My Code:

```
public class MyDataObject : ICustomTypeDescriptor
{
...
    public TypeConverter GetConverter()
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(this, true);
    }
...
}
```

and here the call stack from the stackoverflow exception:

```
System_ni!System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor+AttributeProvider.GetTypeDescriptor(System.Type, System.Object)+4 
System_ni!System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor+TypeDescriptionNode+DefaultTypeDescriptor.System.ComponentModel.ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetAttributes()+64 
System_ni!System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor+AttributeProvider+AttributeTypeDescriptor.GetAttributes()+1b 
System_ni!System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor+TypeDescriptionNode+DefaultTypeDescriptor.System.ComponentModel.ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetAttributes()+7c 
System_ni!System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor+AttributeProvider+AttributeTypeDescriptor.GetAttributes()+1b 
...
...
...
System_ni!System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor+TypeDescriptionNode+DefaultTypeDescriptor.System.ComponentModel.ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetConverter()+83    
System_ni!System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor+TypeDescriptionNode+DefaultTypeDescriptor.System.ComponentModel.ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetConverter()+83    
System_ni!System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor+TypeDescriptionNode+DefaultTypeDescriptor.System.ComponentModel.ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetConverter()+83    
MyDataObject.GetConverter()    
System_ni!System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor+MergedTypeDescriptor.System.ComponentModel.ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetConverter()$##6004537+18    
DevExpress.XtraVerticalGrid.Data.PropertyHelper.GetConverter(System.ComponentModel.ITypeDescriptorContext, System.Object)    
DevExpress.XtraVerticalGrid.Data.PropertyHelper.GetProperties(System.Object, System.ComponentModel.ITypeDescriptorContext, System.Attribute[])    
DevExpress.XtraVerticalGrid.Events.CustomPropertyDescriptorsEventArgs.get_Properties() 
...
My.Program.Main(System.String[])
```

This happens only in automated UI testing - so far...

If it happens, the error stays. Reboot does not resolve it. We have to delete the corresponding dataobject.

We are running VS 2017, .Net 4.6, DevExpress Grid and use Ranorex for automated tests.
Any ideas or hints?

Comment: `TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(this, true);` calls the `public TypeConverter GetConverter()` method. And you are calling that method in your method. You need to create a `Converter` and return the  converter in that method.

Comment: @Eldar this is running in production for 5 years now. If I debug this code it works as expected. Additionally this is the sample implementation! Used by MS (e.g. System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder), Syncfusion, Devexpress and I guess many more.

Comment: Either you say it's working, or it's not working. And it's clearly a recursion, even if it was not endless so far. Your stack says the Recursion comes via GetAttributes().
Maybe somebody has used this class first time with some class with a special set of attributes ? If an error has not shown for a long time, it just can mean there is a new data-situation what hasn't been covered yet.